# Can someone tell me why my string is blank after passing the argument?

Tags: c++, output, concatenation

I cannot seem to get the "full"
to display the concatenation of First and last.
It compiles but when I run it it will appear blank.
Can you tell me why?
Have tried to figure it our for hours.

Here are my declerations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define tax  0.30
#define parking_deductions 10.00
#define overtime_hours 40  
#define max_hours 60 
#define max_pay 99  
string namestring( string first, string last, string full);
```

I'm attempting to pass this module to my main

```
string namestring(string first, string last, string full)
{
    //input name
    cout << "What is your first name? " << endl;
    cout << "first name: " << endl;
    cin >> first;

    cout << "What is your last name? " << endl;
    cout << "last name: " << endl;
    cin >> last;

    //process name
    full = last + " " + first;
    return full;
}
```

By calling it like so

```
namestring(first, last, full );
```

Where I expect the full name input by the user to be displayed below

```
        cout << left << fixed << "            " << "Reg." << "  " << "      Ovt." << "  Hourly" << "   Net" << "  " << "              Gross" << endl;
    cout << left << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(10) << "Name                " << "  Hours" << "  Hours" << " Rate" << "     Pay" << "   Taxes" << "     Deduct" << "    Pay" << endl;
    cout << left << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(10) << "====================" << "  " << "=====" << "  " << "=====" << " " << "=====" << "  " << "======" << "  " << "======" << "  " << "  " << "========" << "  " << "=======" << endl;
    cout << left << setprecision(2) << setw(20) << full << right << " " << right << setw(4) << hours << right << "   " << right << overtime << "  " << right << pay << "  " << right << net_pay << "  " << right << taxs << "    " <<  right << parking_deductions << "     " << right << gross_pay << right << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here to tell what your problem is. Assuming you are calling `cout << namestring("Dr", "Z", "") << endl;` it will work fine; however, if you are trying to use the parameter passed to `namestring` it won't. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant calling code, or as well like to call it here: a **[mcve]**

Comment: Please show the function call also. 
Then we may be able to find out the problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't check if the inputs actually worked. Also, do not use `std::endl` unless you actually need to flush the stream: in the code above the stream will be flushed automatically when `std::cin` is used (`std::cout` is `tie()`d to `std::cin`).

Comment: Why does `namestring` take three string values as parameters? It never uses any of the values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the goal here is to get the following 3 strings,

```
First Name
Last Name
Full Name
```

To do this, you would need to pass the arguments by reference, not by value:

```
void namestring(string& first, string& last, string& full)
{
    //input name
    cout << "What is your first name? " << endl;
    cout << "first name: " << endl;
    cin >> first;

    cout << "What is your last name? " << endl;
    cout << "last name: " << endl;
    cin >> last;

    //process name
    full = last + " " + first;;
}
```

There is also no need to return a string if you pass the "full" string by reference, since the function will fill it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
string namestring(string first, string last, string& full)
//input name
{    
    cout << "What is your first name? " << endl;
    cout << "first name: " << endl;
    cin >> first;

    cout << "What is your last name? " << endl;
    cout << "last name: " << endl;
    cin >> last;

    //process name
    full = last + " " + first;
    return full;
}
```

You are passing the `full` by value. So it's the local copy of the function which is modified. You need it to pass by reference.
If you also want the first and last value you also need to pass it by reference.